# Android. Стандартная папка для логов

Tags: android, логирование

Есть ли в Android некая папка для логов, в которую приложение может их спокойно писать без особых разрешений?

Comment: Любую, полученную через `Context`. Есть дока по файлам - там не очень подробно и понятно, но всё написано https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Comment: Спасибо помогло!